# Ranking based on unequal numbers of discrete observations

Tags: math, geometry, graph-theory, topology

Ranking based on unequal numbers of discrete observations.

We have a set of targets which have different fixed numbers of discrete binary observations (0,1)

We want to compare targets to each other for some overall propensity towards a certain kind of observation(0 or 1) in a way which is not biased by total number of observations of the individual target.

The ranking is also a scale between 0 and 1 and should include an error proportionate to the number of observations (more observations the greater the certainty or propensity to one of the binary observational outcomes)

For example:

On an imaginary map we have countries which can have between 1 and 20 neighbours with discrete boundaries.

We want to rate each country based on the quality of its boundaries with each of its neigbours

So that we can come up with a comparison scheme to rank countries based on the quality of their boundaries.

So for example:

Country A has 8 boundaries (8 neighbours) 4 of which are good boundaries +/- some uncertainty

Country B has 3 boundaries (3 neighbours) 2 of which are good boundaries +/- some uncertainty

So Country B rank > Country A rank ?

The problem requires comparison on features (boundaries) that vary in number for each country.

Intuitively: A comparison scheme suggests that there is some function which is  proportionate to the number of good boundaries and inversely proportionate to the total number of boundaries that each country has.

However, unmoderated, this simple proportionality would be a decaying saw tooth pattern with decreasing frequency with number of boundaries, which impedes simple ranking between countries with disparate number of boundaries.

What would be good approach to rating the countries based on discrete boundaries in such a way that they can be practically compared?

My intuition is this problem, in some guise, is a known problem in some odd branch of discrete maths maybe graph theory? however I have been unable to find an algorithm or mathematical approach to rank countries based on discrete features.

Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: You have to define what "fair" means.

Comment: Thanks for the note: 'fair' here relates to appropriate weighting scheme to compensate for number of neighbors, have updated post.

Comment: You say that "fair" means "appropriate", but what does "appropriate" mean? You need to specify what would be "fair" and "appropriate". For example, in the above example, is it "appropriate" that country B rank ahead of country A?

Comment: Appropriate weighting scheme means that it has to take into account the disparity between having low numbers of boundaries and high numbers of boundaries. A country with fewer boundaries will be disproportionately impacted in ranking compared to a country with multiple boundaries

Comment: And how should you "take it into account"? So far, your explanations have appealed to intuition, but computer programming requires precision. You revised the question to that you are looking for a function that is proportional to the number of good boundaries and inversely proportional to the total number of boundaries. The functions that satisfy this requirement are those of the form `c * good_boundaries / total_boundaries`.

Comment: Hi Raymond, Intuitively one potential function that might approach the problem would be be of the form "f" is proportionate to "good boundaries" /"total boundaries" however this function is not friendly for comparison between countries due to its behavior. My feeling is this problem is a known problem in some obscure branch of maths maybe graph theory? however I have been unable to find an equivalent. Hence I am searching for an algorithm which may work for this situation and play nice with the discrete math.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227479/discussion-between-seand-and-raymond-chen).